# How to use same conditional statement for different variables in java?

Tags: java, netbeans

My program suppose to get mark from user for each subject using this conditional statement. And the output is the subject's grade and the total GPA for four subjects.

I want to use this conditional statement for other four variable (subjectA,subjectB,subjectC,subjectD) replacing "discrete". And I want to access them for output. Is there any way to shorten the code instead of writing the same conditional statement for each variable ?

```
if (discrete>=90 && discrete <=100)
      {discreteGrade= "A+" ;
        discreteGPA=4.00;}
 else if (discrete>=80 && discrete <=89)
  {discreteGrade= "A" ;
   discreteGPA=4.00;}
     else if (discrete>=75 && discrete <=79)
     {discreteGrade= "A-" ;
     discreteGPA=3.67;}
       else if (discrete>=70 && discrete <=74)
        {discreteGrade= "B+" ;
         discreteGPA=3.33;}
           else if (discrete>=65 && discrete <=69)
          {discreteGrade= "B" ;
           discreteGPA=3.00;}
               else if (discrete>=60 && discrete <=64)
               {discreteGrade= "B-" ;
                discreteGPA=2.67;}
                  else if (discrete>=55 && discrete <=59)
                 {discreteGrade= "C+" ;
                  discreteGPA=2.33;}
                     else if (discrete>=50 && discrete <=54)
                     {discreteGrade= "C" ;
                     discreteGPA=2.00;}
                         else if (discrete>=45 && discrete <=49)
                        {discreteGrade= "C-" ;
                         discreteGPA=1.67;}
                             else if (discrete>=40 && discrete <=44)
                            {discreteGrade= "D+" ;
                            discreteGPA=1.33;}
                                  else if (discrete>=35 && discrete <=39)
                                    {discreteGrade= "D" ;
                                 discreteGPA=1.00;}
                                       else
                                {discreteGrade= "F" ;
                                   discreteGPA=0.00;}
```

Comment: Not what you're asking, but shouldn't all those `||` actually be `&&`?

Comment: Also, I suggest you let your IDE reformat that code. You'll find it *a lot* more readable.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca just realized those `||` that should be `&&` .thank you! and how to let my IDE reformat the code?

Comment: Alt+Shift+F  reformats your code.

Comment: To everybody answering, I urge you all to read the question more carefully. OP's not asking how to rewrite that piece of code to be more compact, they're asking how to apply the same logic to four grades instead of just one.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, You're right, but I do think there is some value in shortening the code. Shortening the code (and creating a generic method that returns the proper grade) would be, imo, a correct answer. I think OP is mostly concerned with the length of the code since they would have to copy-paste it 4 times. Perhaps with shorter code they would be less concerned with this issue, especially with a proper method created.

Comment: I wonder where the subjectA, subjectB, ... fit into his code.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I think that OP intended that subjectA, B, etc... takes the place of "discreteGrade" and "discreteGPA", which makes me understand OPs confusion.  I think they would have made a method, but didnt understand how to make a method return two values, which would require an object. There is an answer below that I think adequately handles this.

Comment: @thetechnician94 I fear the OP has chosen the wrong subject.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Im not sure I would say that, but yes, they are probably just getting started with code. Glad a community like this exists to help them with concepts like this.

Answer (score 3):

So, I would try to avoid such IF-ELSE statements. They are really hard to understand, write and extend. Here is a better solution.

```
public class Grade {
    private double min;
    private double gpa;
    private String mark;
    public Grade(double min, double gpa, String mark) {
        this.min = min;
        this.gpa = gpa;
        this.mark = mark;
    }
}
```

This stores the minimum discrete needed to obtain it, the GPA and the string representation (A+, A, A-, etc.)

Now, we have a Grader class that calculates the grade. Sorry if my English is not on par and the naming are not correct, but I hope you get the point.

```
public class Grader {
    private List<Grade> grades = Arrays.asList(new Grade(90, 4.00, "A+"),
            new Grade(80, 4.00, "A"),
            new Grade(75, 3.67, "A-"));
    public Grade getGrade(double discrete) {
        Iterator<Grade> iterator = grades.listIterator();
        Grade grade = iterator.next();
        while (grade.getMin() > discrete) {
            grade = iterator.next();
        }

        return grade;
    }
}
```

Some improvements can be done here (for example, negative or invalid marks received, but this is just a proof of concept). What it does, it iterates the list of possible grades until it gets to the correct one. Just make sure you add all the possible grades in the list. I only added the first three.

Now, the class Grader does not care for what subject it receives the grade. You can call it multiple times like this:

```
Grader grader = new Grader();
Grade forSubjectA = grader.grade(discreteForA);
Grade forSubjectB = grader.grade(discreteForB);
...
```

Comment: I think so far this is the closest to what OP wants, but maybe you could show them how it ties back in with their "four variable" request? That is, how this class can be reused for each.

Comment: The Grader class does not care what it receives as the discrete parameter. It can be for any subject. 
Wondering why I got the -1 though...

Comment: I think that it was because the question asked how OP could not reuse the whole If-else block four times. While this class makes perfect sense to me, I think it would be valuable to show that the class is reusable and can be used to figure out all four of his variables, though I didnt -1 you.

Comment: Edited my answer to show how the grader can be used multiple times with different discrete. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps you could complete your grader class to handle all cases.  It may help the OP.

Comment: I don't think StackOverflow is for "do this for me", but to provide direction and support for actual problems. If OP can't even be bothered to complete the statement, than my answer is of no use since he won't even be bothered to understand why it was done this way and will ask again for any simple problem knowing he will get everything without the need to think at all.

Comment: @PetrePopescu are you using method for this way? may I know what is `Grade forSubjectA = grader.grade(discreteForA);
Grade forSubjectB = grader.grade(discreteForB);`   for?  is `discreteForA` is a variable? and to display the mark and gpa for subjectA which one should I call? should I call  `discreteForA`  ? Sorry if this is a bad question. asking for clarification.

Comment: yes, ```discreteForA``` and ```discreteForB``` are the discrete values for which you want to get the GPA and the grade letter. Now, I don't know what "SubjectA" is sicne you did not provide any data structures. I don't know how your data is structured and how you get the discrete from a subject. I just re-wrote the long IF-ELSE statements to be easier to maintain, easier to read and reusable.

Comment: oh now I know my problem. should provide my data structures next time. Thanks for the help. for clarification,  `getMin` is used to get the min from user, right?

Comment: No. ```getMin()``` returns the minimum number of points you have to get in order to receive that specific grade.

Answer (score 1):

discrete is read from the commandline 1st parameter

```
        int[] discrvals = {90,80,75,70,65,60,55,50,45,40,35};
        String[] discrgrades = {
                  "A+","A","A-","B+","B","B-","C+","C","C-","D+", "D","F"};
        double[] discrgpas = {
           4.0,4.0,3.67,3.33,3.0,2.67,2.33,2.00,1.67,1.33,1.0, 0.0};

        int discrete = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i<discrvals.length; i++){
          if (discrete > discrvals[i] ) {
             break;
          }
        }
        System.out.println( discrgrades[i] + "/" + discrgpas[i] );
```

Comment: may I know what is `discrvals` and `discrgpas` stand for?

Comment: @Syazwani2191 "Discrete Values" and "Discrete GPAS", respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I mean, I would start from the lowest grade, so you can cut some of the conditions.

```
if (discrete < 35) {
    discreteGrade = "F";
    discreteGPA = 0.00;
} else if (discrete < 40) {
    discreteGrade = "D";
    discreteGPA = 1.00;
} else if (discrete < 45) {
    discreteGrade = "D+";
    discreteGPA = 1.33;
} else if (discrete < 50) {
    discreteGrade = "C-";
    discreteGPA = 1.67;
} else if (discrete < 55) {
    discreteGrade = "C";
    discreteGPA = 2.00;
} else if (discrete < 60) {
    discreteGrade = "C+";
    discreteGPA = 2.33;
} else if (discrete < 65) {
    discreteGrade = "B-";
    discreteGPA = 2.67;
} else if (discrete < 70) {
    discreteGrade = "B";
    discreteGPA = 3.00;
} else if (discrete < 75) {
    discreteGrade = "B+";
    discreteGPA = 3.33;
} else if (discrete < 80) {
    discreteGrade = "A-";
    discreteGPA = 3.67;
} else if (discrete < 90) {
    discreteGrade= "A";
    discreteGPA = 4.00;
} else {
    discreteGrade = "A+";
    discreteGPA = 4.00;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment you can also try a switch case and you want to put && but you might not need the || part because your if statement  is already declaring the next step like

```
if(discrete>89 )// it don't matter  if it is greater then 100 because it is still going to be an a+
{
   discreteGrade= "A+";
   discreteGPA=4.00;
}else if(discreet > 79)
{
  // your code here because it will catch the the fact that it is already
  // < 90 because the first if statement says it is already greater than 89.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I could make for the question. Not just four subjects, I have made it as an array of subject marks so that it is flexible for multiple subjects.

This is not a complete answer, but an idea for you to build on.

```
public class S06 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student s = new Student(89.5, 90.0, 45.0, 99.5); // Marks of 4 subjects
    List<Grade> studentGrade = s.getGradesForMarks(); // Grades of 4 subjects
    System.out.println(studentGrade);
  }
}

class Student {

  private Double[] marks;

  public Student(Double... marks) {
    this.marks = marks;
  }

  public List<Grade> getGradesForMarks() {
    return Arrays.stream(marks).map(this::getGradeForMark).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  private Grade getGradeForMark(double mark) {
    return Arrays.stream(Grade.values())
        .filter(g -> mark > g.minMarks && mark <= g.maxMarks) //Your conditions go here!
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Unable to grade mark , " + mark));
  }

  enum Grade {
    GRADE_A_PLUS("A+", 4.00, 100, 91),
    GRADE_A("A", 4.00, 90, 81),
    GRADE_A_MINUS("A-", 3.69, 80, 71),
    OTHERS("O", 3.00, 70, 0);

    String discreteGrade;
    Double discreteGPA;
    Double maxMarks; 
    Double minMarks;

    Grade(String discreteGrade, double discreteGPA, double maxMarks, double minMarks) {
      this.discreteGrade = discreteGrade;
      this.discreteGPA = discreteGPA;
      this.maxMarks = maxMarks;
      this.minMarks = minMarks;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope the variable names are self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer if i understood:

```
        if (discrete>=90 && discrete <=100)
          {discreteGrade= "A+" ;
            discreteGPA=4.00;}
     else if (discrete>=80 && discrete <=89)
      {discreteGrade= "A" ;
       discreteGPA=4.00;}
         else if (discrete>=75 && discrete <=79)
         {discreteGrade= "A-" ;
         discreteGPA=3.67;}
           else if (discrete>=70 && discrete <=74)
            {discreteGrade= "B+" ;
             discreteGPA=3.33;}
               else if (discrete>=65 && discrete <=69)
              {discreteGrade= "B" ;
               discreteGPA=3.00;}
                   else if (discrete>=60 && discrete <=64)
                   {discreteGrade= "B-" ;
                    discreteGPA=2.67;}
                      else if (discrete>=55 && discrete <=59)
                     {discreteGrade= "C+" ;
                      discreteGPA=2.33;}
            else if (discrete>=45 && discrete <=49)
                            {discreteGrade= "C-" ;
                             discreteGPA=1.67;}
                                 else if (discrete>=40 && discrete <=44)
                                {discreteGrade= "D+" ;
                                discreteGPA=1.33;}
                                      else if (discrete>=35 && discrete <=39)
                                        {discreteGrade= "D" ;
```

or simpler:

```
    if (discrete < 35) {
    discreteGrade = "F";
    discreteGPA = 0.00;
} else if (discrete < 40) {
    discreteGrade = "D";
    discreteGPA = 1.00;
} else if (discrete < 45) {
    discreteGrade = "D+";
    discreteGPA = 1.33;
} else if (discrete < 50) {
    discreteGrade = "C-";
    discreteGPA = 1.67;
} else if (discrete < 55) {
    discreteGrade = "C";
    discreteGPA = 2.00;
} else if (discrete < 60) {
    discreteGrade = "C+";
    discreteGPA = 2.33;
} else if (discrete < 65) {
    discreteGrade = "B-";
    discreteGPA = 2.67;
} else if (discrete < 70) {
    discreteGrade = "B";
    discreteGPA = 3.00;
} else if (discrete < 75) {
    discreteGrade = "B+";
    discreteGPA = 3.33;
} else if (discrete < 80) {
    discreteGrade = "A-";
    discreteGPA = 3.67;
} else if (discrete < 90) {
    discreteGrade= "A";
    discreteGPA = 4.00;
} else {
    discreteGrade = "A+";
    discreteGPA = 4.00;
}
```

maybe this works better, and someone might have already sent this as his more beter and simpler.